# Bluetooth.ACTION_FOUND not registering

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth device.

If:

1. They have already paired and connected to the device
2. it becomes unplugged
3. then it becomes plugged back in

I would like to auto-connect to it. That's why I'm listening to ACTION_FOUND.

My code is fairly simple. The ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED and  ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED work just fine. I am completely unable to get the ACTION_FOUND to catch though. My "INTENT RECEIVED" log message never prints…

I feel like I am missing something simple. Thanks!

```
public void registerReceiver() {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.e(TAG, "REGISTERING RECEIVER");

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    mainActivity.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.e(TAG, "INTENT RECEIVED: " + String.valueOf(action));

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // … some stuff … 

        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            autoConnectDevice();

        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            disconnectDevice();
        }
    }
};

public void unregisterReceiver() {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.e(TAG, "UNREGISTERING RECEIVER");
    mainActivity.unregisterReceiver(receiver);      
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your AndroidManifest.xml? BTW Did you tried to comment the ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED and the ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED lines when you are adding them to the `IntentFilter`? Just for try.

Comment: I have not added any intent-related code to the Manifest. I will try the other suggestion and edit my answer

Comment: @aragablarga I imagine that you already added the BLUETOOTH permission at your manifest, did you try with the BLUETOOTH_ADMIN and BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED as well?

Comment: Yes, bluetooth is set up. I can connect and process on my device successfully. It is just this one case that is not firing the intent. I have BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN

Comment: Maybe you should add this one as well check [BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED) Just to try.

Comment: According to the documentation: "Allows applications to pair bluetooth devices without user interaction, and to allow or disallow phonebook access or message access." I am already paired to the device. I simply want to be notified when it is powered on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the ACTION_FOUND event only fires when you are running device discovery with the intent to pair your device to another. It would not fire when an already paired device comes back into range. Unfortunately, there does not appear to be an event for the case that you want.

Your best bet will be to start an AsycTask or Thread when the connection is lost and try to reconnect until successful or until you hit an arbitrary time limit and give up.

Comment: I didn't want this to be true, but after changing my code to listen to every available Bluetooth Action, I think it is. There is no intent for a device that becomes reconnected.